# How to import TimeLineMax into my angular2 component?

Tags: angular, gsap

My component looks like this:

```
 import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
//import {TL} from 'angular2/TimelineMax';
@Component({
    selector: 'opning',
    templateUrl: './components/opning/opning.html',
    styleUrls: ['./components/opning/opning.css']
})
export class OpenCmp {
    constructor() {
        console.log("played");

        var tl = new TimelineMax();
        var logo = $("#logo");
        tl.from(logo, 4, { z: 500, y: 74, visibility: "visible" });
        //tl.from(logo, 2, { left: "632px" });
        tl.play();

    }
}
```

My TimeLineMax.min.js is loaded my my main index.html trough a .ts script and gets loaded fine. I just need to import timelinemax so i can use it in my component class. Cant find any examples on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solutions via greensocks forums.

I include the TimelineMax.min.js and TweenLite.min.js in main index.html not using systemjs loader but just loading like normal, then in my component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import "gsap";
@Component({
    selector: 'opning',
    templateUrl: './components/opning/opning.html',
    styleUrls: ['./components/opning/opning.css']
})
export class OpenCmp {
    constructor() {
        var obj = $('#logo');
        var cl = $('#myTab');
        var tbc = $('#tbc');
        var tl = new TimelineMax({ delay: 0.1 });
        tl.from(obj, 0.4, { y: -200 });
        tl.from(cl, 0.3, { x: -1700 }, "=-0.4");
        tl.from(tbc, 0.5, { opacity: 0 });
        tl.play();
        console.log('played');
    }
}
```

Now gsap works fine in Angular2

Answer (score 1):

When you import your own internal modules, you should use relative paths starting from the folder where the hosting module is located:

```
import {TL} from './TimelineMax';
```

This assumes that opencmp.ts is in the same folder as timelinemax.ts:

```
root
  +opencmp.ts
  +timelinemax.ts
```

If timelinemax is from an external module, then find the module in the ./node_modules folder, and use the relative path to the ts file.

For example, if your node_modules are organized like this:

```
root
   +node_modules
       +angular2
       +gsap
           +src
               +uncompressed
                    +timelinemax.ts
```

(which you should have imported using a package manager like npm: `npm install gsap`).

Then import the module like this:

```
 import {TL} from 'gsap/src/uncompressed/timelinemax';
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mientjan/typescript-tweenlite-definition/master/TimelineMax.d.ts , not sure if that one is correct. Then also i renamed TimelineMax.min.js to TimelineMax.js, but now i get this error: GET http://localhost:5555/node_modules/TweenLite.js 404 (Not Found) 
And I didnt declare /node_modules/TweenLite.js anywhere, but anyway i think im on the wrong track using that .ts file, im kinda lost here

Comment: just try: import {TL} from 'gsap/src/uncompressed/timelinemax';
I did a search for timeline max and found that it is an external module, and I imported it with npm and found where its located.

Comment: I have installed that package, but having trouble importing it. I Tried " import {TL} from 'gsap/src/uncompressed/timelinemax';" but it didnt work (app\components\opning\opning.ts(5,18): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'gsap/src/uncompressed/timelinemax'.) But also that doesnt include any .ts files

Comment: If you are using VS 2015, right click the project, go to properties and TypeScriipt build, change Module System to CommonJS. I don't know the details of the module loader you're using... but this is what I do.

Comment: No idea, im using this: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed and working from there..

Answer (score 0):

You need to have timelinemax.d.ts definition file, if they are not provided by library developers than you need to create / write it.

Comment: Tried to find some of the ts files like that i googled myself into and fiddled around but didnt get it to work. But is it like this for other js-files i want to import into angular2 to also? Seems kinda hard

Comment: Ok, now i see that you provide this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mientjan/typescript-tweenlite-definition/master/TimelineMax.d.ts This is type definition, but without defined module, so i changed this to: https://gist.github.com/vladotesanovic/7b1773ab0c0b451efeb6 ( note last few lines ). Also i put few methods to be static, for purpuse of this example only.

Inside my code i go with: `import * as TL from "TimelineMax" `

Now i can call static methods with TL... or create instance of this class...